# How to cycle through a list of functions in a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am fairly new to programming in R, so I apologize if this question is too basic. I am trying to study the properties of OLS with error terms created by three different processes (i.e., normal1, normal2, and chi-square). I include these in a list, 'fun_list'.

I would like to iterate through 1,000 (iter) regressions, each with sample size 500 (n). I would like to save all 1,000 X 500 observations in a dataset (big_data) as well as the regression results (reg_results).

At the end of the program, I would like 1,000 regressions for each of the three processes (for a total of 3,000 regressions). I have set up nested loops for the three functions on one level and the 1,000 iterations on a different (sub-) level. I am having trouble getting the program to loop through the three different functions. I am not sure how to call out each element of the list in this embedded loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 library(psych)
 library(arm)
 library(dplyr)
 library(fBasics)
 library(sjstats)

 #set sample size and number of iterations
 set.seed(12345)
 n <- 500
 iter <- 1000

 #setting empty vectors. Probably a better way to do this. :)
 bn <- rep(NA,iter)
 sen <- rep(NA,iter)


 #these are the three functions I want to use to generate en,
 #which is the error term below. I want one loop for each of the three.
 # I can get f1, f2 and f3 to work independently, but I can't get the list 
 #to work to cycle through all three. 

 f1 <- function (n)  {rnorm(n, 0, 2)} 
 f2 <- function (n)  {rnorm(n, 0, 10)} 
 f3 <- function (n)  {rchisq(n, 2)}
 fun_list <- list(f1, f2, f3)

 #following line starting point for saving all iterations in one big 
 #dataset

 datalist = list()

 #if I remove the following line (for (j ....)), I can get this to work by 
 #referencing each function independently (i.e., using 'en <- f1(n)').

 for (j in fun_list) {
    for (s in 1:iter) {

  #  en <- f1(n)
     en <- fun_list[[1]]
     x <- rnorm(n, 0, .5)
     yn <- .3*x + en

#this is the part that saves the data#
dat <- data.frame(yn, x, en)
dat$s <- s
datalist[[s]] <- dat

#### run model for normal data and save parameters###
lm1n <- lm(yn ~ x)
int.hatn <- coef (lm1n)[1]
b.hatn <- coef (lm1n)[2]
se.hatn <- se.coef (lm1n) [2]

##save them for each iteration
bn[s] = b.hatn
sen[s] = se.hatn
 }
 }

 reg_results<- tibble(bn, sen)

 big_data = do.call(rbind,datalist)
```

When using the loop, I get the following error:

Error in 0.3 * x + en : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I am assuming this is because I do not fully understand how to call out each of the three functions in the list.

Comment: Hi, the issue is in `yn <- .3*x + en` you try to add a vector `x` to a function, which is meaningless. What are you trying to achieve with this line?

Comment: I am trying to add each of the three distributions. 'en' is supposed to represent the error term that runs 1,000 iterations for the first (normal1), 1,000 for the second, etc. So I am trying to take .3*x (another random variable) and add the error term.  know I am missing something here....

Comment: You need to actually call the function, e.g. with `.3*x + en(n)`

Comment: Thank you. I just tried that, but there is still a minor problem. I don't know how to call each of the three functions in the list. This is incorrect, right: en <- fun_list[[1]] ? I think I need to modify this in some way.

Comment: Now you call only one function, the first, you want to call the 3 of them at the same time?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm trying to invoke one function like normal1 (in the outer loop), run 1,000 regressions (inner loop). Then I'm trying to use the outer loop to go to the second and third functions (normal2 and chisquare).

Comment: So if you do `en <- j` it should work since `j` represent the element of `fun_list` when you loop over it

Comment: That did not work, so I tried en <- j(n) and yn <- .3x + en. The model ran, but it something is wrong because I only have 1,000 regression results when it should be 3000. So the loop is not working properly or I'm not storing them properly.

Comment: if you do `for (j in c(1:length(fun_list)))` and then `en <- fun_list[[j]]` ?

Comment: Yo also have a clear storage issue, indeed the size of `bn` and `sen` is only `niter` and you store them only using `s`, so for each loop in `j` you erase them. You can define them as  `bn <- c()` and  `sen <- c()` and then increase their size by adding new value in each loop iteration with `bn= c(bn,b.hatn)` and  `sen = c(sen,se.hatn)`

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time and energy, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What is the issue if you run the code given in my answer?

Comment: Wow! I think I sent that before I saw your answer. I think I follow your code, but I'm getting an error: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame –

Comment: Now it should work. You where trying to store the function itself in the data frame, I think you rather want to store `en(n)`. Note I introduced a temporary variable to store it, because if you call it two times (to compute `yn` and to store it in the df), you will get different values. I also corrected a typo at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution which wraps the multiple points discussed in the comments:

```
 library(psych)
 library(arm)
 library(dplyr)
 library(fBasics)
 library(sjstats)

 #set sample size and number of iterations
 set.seed(12345)
 n <- 500
 iter <- 1000

 #setting empty vectors. Probably a better way to do this. :)
 bn <- c()
 sen <- c()


 #these are the three functions I want to use to generate en,
 #which is the error term below. I want one loop for each of the three.
 # I can get f1, f2 and f3 to work independently, but I can't get the list 
 #to work to cycle through all three. 

 f1 <- function (n)  {rnorm(n, 0, 2)} 
 f2 <- function (n)  {rnorm(n, 0, 10)} 
 f3 <- function (n)  {rchisq(n, 2)}
 fun_list <- list(f1, f2, f3)

 #following line starting point for saving all iterations in one big 
 #dataset

 datalist = list()

 #if I remove the following line (for (j ....)), I can get this to work by 
 #referencing each function independently (i.e., using 'en <- f1(n)').

 for (j in c(1:length(fun_list))) {
   en <- fun_list[[j]]
   for (s in 1:iter) {
     x <- rnorm(n, 0, .5)
     random_part <- en(n)
     yn <- .3*x + random_part

     #this is the part that saves the data#
     dat <- data.frame(yn, x, random_part)
     dat$s <- s
     datalist[[s]] <- dat

     #### run model for normal data and save parameters###
     lm1n <- lm(yn ~ x)
     int.hatn <- coef(lm1n)[1]
     b.hatn <- coef(lm1n)[2]
     se.hatn <- se.coef(lm1n)[2]

     ##save them for each iteration
     bn = c(bn,b.hatn)
     sen = c(sen,se.hatn)
   }
 }

 reg_results<- tibble(bn, sen)

 big_data = do.call(rbind,datalist)
```